# Built-in view login : Error handling and good practice

Tags: python, django

I would like to use the Django's built-in login view : `django.contrib.auth.views.login`

This view does a great job. It detects when a login is wrong and when the account is not yet validated BUT the error messages are very short.

For a not activated account:

> This account is inactive.

**Do you know the proper way to be more verbose?**

I prefer something like:

> This account is inactive. An email was sent to you with an activation link.

Actually, I do the login by myself and I pass to the template an error context:

```
context = {}
  if request.method == 'POST':
    email = request.POST['email']
    password = request.POST['password']

    user = authenticate(username=email, password=password)
    if user is not None:
      if user.is_active:
        login_django(request, user)
        return redirect('consumer.views.dashboard')
      else:
        context = {'error': 'disable_account'}
    else:
      context = {'error': 'invalid_account'}
  return render(request, 'login.html', context)
```

and in the template I can check what kind of error is it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you are reporting is actually not due to the `django.contrib.auth.views.login`, but to the form it uses.

In `django.contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm`:

```
error_messages = {
    'invalid_login': _("Please enter a correct %(username)s and password. "
                       "Note that both fields may be case-sensitive."),
    'inactive': _("This account is inactive."),
}
```

I think you have two options:

1. You subclass the form `django.contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm`, change `error_messages`, and pass the new form to the login view as argument of `authentication_form`.
2. If you use [translation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/), you can translate the string "This account is inactive." to the string you want.

It seems to me that the first option is the best practice since translation should not be used to change messages' content.

Comment: The form solution is good but can we do better ? It's a long message, I think its place is in the template, don't you ? Thank you

Comment: Well, I think the size of the message should not be relevant to decide where it should belong on the code or to a template. It is more a matter of [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming)): In this case, form.clean tests if user is active, thus, makes sense to put the message on the form.